# How to quickly change language spell check in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I often write messages in two languages, and I would like to change language spell check quickly. Is there any shortcut for this?

I can use right mouse click and then navigate to change language, but doing this with some shortcut will be much more convenient.

Maybe there is a way of adding a new custom shortcut for this?

Comment: It would be very nice to have this functionality in the future. I'm constantly switching between two languages, and it's something that happens to many people.

Comment: @AugustoBarreto Same problem here. But it seems that the Google support doesn't understand the need for a solution. Check out Natalie's answer, she completely missed the point: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/jMUMrifprZs

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this, it might make your life a little bit easier.

1. Go to chrome://settings/advanced.
2. Scroll down to the bottom and click "Show advanced settings..."
3. Go to languages then click "Language and input settings..." button.
4. Add language of your choice. Click "Done" and exit.

Once you done change setting you can right click on the textbox or text area. You will find spell-checker option. Click on that you can select your newly added language.
Hope this is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 47, Chrome supports multi-lingual spell-checking. I didn't find too much information about it, only [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/isLjibRZpgo) because I came across an issue with it (I had to remove and add "Spanish" again to make it work).

> With Chrome Version 47, there is a new schema for multilingual
>   Spell-Checking. Chrome now automatically detects what language(s) you
>   are using. To specify which languages you want to check, please do
>   this: Click the Menu Icon (≡), then Settings -> Advanced Settings,
>   then scroll down to Languages. Now click the Button [Settings] to set
>   the languages you want to use for spelling.

NOTE: And for those who also use Firefox besides using Chrome, a new equivalent extension has been released: [automatic-dictionary-switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/automatic-dictionary-switcher/)

Comment: +1 got here trying to find out why the quick menu for selecting the language for the spell checker disappeared... and found the answer :)